# DATEADD throwing an error when adding MAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to get the sum of sales for the last 3 months. not including the unfinished month which is this month.
I have this Dax but its not accepting the DATEADD with the MAX. Is there any workaround?

Measure1 =  CALCULATE (
SUM ( table1[Sales] ),
DATESINPERIOD (
table1[date],
DATEADD( MAX ( table1[date] ), -1,MONTH),
-3,
MONTH
)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEADD` function requires a set of dates to computation. That is why it not works with `MAX`, which returns single value. Find more [here](https://dax.guide/dateadd/).

You need to find the maximum date in the dataset, then filter out the current month from the date table. Try the measure as follows:

```
Measure1 = 
VAR maxDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        ALL('Calendar' )
    )
VAR firstDay = DATE( YEAR( maxDate ), MONTH( maxDate ), 1 ) 
VAR maxK = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Calendar'[Date] ),
        'Calendar'[Date] < firstDay
    )
VAR result = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM( AmountPaid[PaymentAmt] ), 
        DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], maxK, -3, MONTH )
    )
return result
```

The `maxK` part calculates maximum date excluding the latest month in my dataset. You have to adjust the measure a bit for your needs (e.g. use `TODAY()` instead `maxDate`).

Hope it helps.